# How to use regular expressions to match strings that are not the same at both ends

Tags: regex

For example

"abbedc",  --->   "abbedc".
 "abbbcde",  --->  "abbcde".   first a, the first b, third b, c, d, e.
"aabbbcd", --->  "abbcd".  second a, the first b,third b,the first c and the first d, .
    "aaabbbc" --->  "abbc".   third a, first b, third b, c.
"aabbcc" --->    "abbc".  second a, first b, second b, first c.

Comment: I am afraid that your requirement is not clear enough. Can you rephrase your question?

Comment: And please add regex flavor (language/tool).

Comment: @ClasG js or python

Comment: @ZunTzu match on both sides different letters. This is clear ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will match the pieces individually.
https://regex101.com/r/vJVOGt/1

`(?:([a-z])(?!\1)([a-z])(?:(?!\2)[a-z]$)?)+`

You'd have to join the pieces though.

```
 (?:
      ( [a-z] )                     # (1)
      (?! \1 )
      ( [a-z] )                     # (2)
      (?:
           (?! \2 )
           [a-z] $ 
      )?
 )+
```

Comment: because i can't feedback ,my reputation less than 15,This solve my part question,I test "abacdcf" is not.